# PowerPivot DAX formula if then for dates

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I have a column named `ExpireDate` in my PowerPivot table (not PowerBI) and want to make another column based on the value of `Today's Date` - `ExpireDate` with a DAX formula like below:

```
=if(Format([ExpireDate] -today(), "General Number") <= 90, "Less than 3 months", 
 if(90 < Format( [ExpireDate] -today() ,"General Number") <= 180, " 3 to 6 months", 
 if([Format (ExpireDate]-today() ,"General Number") > 180, "More than 6 months","Other"))
```

But this formula keeps showing error messages, saying it needs a proper formula.  Anybody knows how to deal with this problem? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Excel 2016, and your table name is "Table":

```
=
VAR Expiration = Table[ExpireDate] - TODAY ()
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        Expiration <= 90, "Less than 3 months",
        Expiration <= 180, " 3 to 6 months",
        Expiration > 180, "More than 6 months",
        "Other"
    )
```

Comment: Hi Rado, thanks for your answer! Your code does what I wanted, so thanks a lot for that. I am surprised the structure looks completely different from what I built. This explains why I couldn't seem to get my code working. Thanks again!

Comment: @user71812 - glad it solved your problem; please mark it as an aswer to close the question. Also, this link might help you better understand how it works: https://powerpivotpro.com/2012/06/dax-making-the-case-for-switch/